# Помогите построить изображение

Tags: delphi

Помогите пожалуйста построить изображение в Delphi.

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Объект `TCanvas`, методы `LineTo`, `MoveTo`, свойства: `Pen`, `Brush`.

Знания: Математика 7-8 классов, косинус, синус, радиус, окружность и круг.
Информатика 7-8 классов, там как раз рисование в паскале точно было.

Компонент `TImage`, `TPaintBox` и их свойства: `Bitmap.Canvas`, У `TPaintBox` вроде сразу идут методы от `Canvas`.